# Restarting a setInterval() in Javascript/jQuery (without clearInterval)

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, setinterval, eventtrigger

I'm working on ui tabs built using jQuery. Everything works except for one issue - I did a setInterval that runs a function that does a trigger("click") so that it goes to the next tab after 5000 miliseconds. It runs through each tab fine, the issue is that if the user manually clicks on a tab, the timer for the setInterval does not restart back at 0. For example if a user were to start on tab1 at 0 miliseconds and clicks on tab2 at 2000 miliseconds, the setInterval doesn't go back to 0, it would start at 2000 and run to 5000 miliseconds and would subsequently goto tab3. I understand why it's happening, I just wonder if there were a way to restart the setInterval timing without having to do a clearInterval() and creating an entirely new setInterval(). Any insight would be appreciated.

**Update**

Thanks for the replies - The reason I was trying to avoid using clearInterval was because I was having issues of how to write the code in a way where the clearInterval would stop the setInterval completely. The code is setup to track whenever a user has clicked a tab. The problem is the auto change function utilizes trigger('click'), so it runs the clearInterval function I wrote also when the tabs auto-change. It seems to run fairly fine on its own, but once the user starts clicking on tabs, the setInterval behaves unusually and switches tabs unpredictably. I suspect what is happening is that several setIntervals are running at once... Here's the code (If you haven't guessed it already, I'm pretty new at javascript/jquery). I've commented out parts so that it's functional, but it still doesn't function as I intended (from first post).

```
// auto change tabs
            if( options.interval ) {

                function timerCom() {
                    if( !$(".controller").hasClass('paused') ) {
                        var i = $(".tab-current > a").attr("rel");
                        //alert(i);
                        if( i == 3 ) {i = 0};
                        $container
                            .find('a')
                            .eq(i)
                            .trigger('click');
                    }    
                }

                //$("#promo-items > li > a").click(function () {
                    //var timer;
                    //if( timer != null ) {clearInterval(timer);}
                    timer = setInterval(timerCom, options.interval);

                //});

            }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please just edit your question if you need to provide additional information. Use comments for specific questions about answers. SO is not a forum, the answer field is strictly reserved for answers to the question.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no way to restart a timer set by `setInterval` without clearing the timer.

Answer (score 4):

You can't really alter intervals or timeouts, only clear them.  That said it should be a simple thing to create a function that clears the interval, and then starts a new but identical one immediately with a fresh time value.

```
var intervalID;
var resetTimer = function() {
  if (intervalID) { clearInterval(intervalID) };
  intervalID = setInterval(function() {
    console.log('doing stuff!');
  }, 5000);
};
```

Comment: that way of using braces makes the code almost unreadable :P. Braces should be on their own lines

Comment: I have no interest in the debate, but as a matter of fact, Google's coding standard says "Because of implicit semicolon insertion, always start your curly braces on the same line as whatever they're opening." http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml

Answer (score 1):

```
timer = setInterval(function() {
  timerCom();
}, options.interval);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this post is well over 2 years old, but I ran into a similar problem just now, and I found a solution.

I was writing an image scroller that would automatically shift to the next image after a set amount of time, and whenever I clicked the navigation buttons, the transitions moved double-time.

**Here's my solution:**

Make the interval variable (`timer` in your case) somewhat global.

i.e. in the `options` section (assuming it was defined earlier, and then later assigned), add a null `timer` variable.

```
var options = {
'interval',
//Other variables
'timer',
};
```

Then, call `clearInterval` twice when you handle the click event.

```
$("#promo-items > li > a").click(function () {

if( options.timer != null ) {
clearInterval(options.timer);
clearInterval(options.timer);
}

options.timer = setInterval(timerCom, options.interval);

});
```

Worked like a charm for me.

Again, sorry if this is wayyyy too late.