# Can't restart setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, restart, clearinterval

I'm writing a little javascript game and simulated an avatar class.

I have a variable (function doesn't work,!) that moves the tail of my avatar constantly.

```
function avatar(){    
  this.switchTail=setInterval(function (){
    if (ava.getTail() == rainbow)
      {ava.setTail(rainbowUpsideDown);}
    else {
      console.log("wooo,I'm alive");
      ava.setTail(rainbow);}}
  ,300)
  ...
}
```

I have some problems with it, First of all it starts automatically when I run the game. And second of all, I don't want the tail to be flipping when I'm in the menu, or at pause. So I wrote a function to kill it

```
avatar() { 
  ....

  this.stopSwitchingTail=function() {clearInterval(this.switchTail)}
  ....
}
```

But after killing it, how do I restart the switchingTail?

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4328148/restarting-a-setinterval-in-javascript-jquery-without-clearinterval#4328173

Comment: From your question, you just need to call `avator()` again by the looks up it. Also theres a good chance you're using the `this` keyword incorrectly judging by that code segment

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p5nFb/

Comment: megawac solution worked :D, I simulated an avatar class with local variable tailInterval, and created this.switchTail and this.stopSwitchingTail like in the jsfiddle ;)

Comment: For some reason this question caught my attention. I see that @megawac has already provided a good solution (perhaps you should post it as an answer) but if you need several instances of Avatar [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BeUYL/1/) may be useful.

Comment: I didn't feel like I understood the question well enough to post an answer. I updated your fiddle a bit @Moob http://jsfiddle.net/BeUYL/4/ only because not having static items of a class on the prototype bugs me. Anyway, your solution fits his question better than mine - post it ;) - update /3/ i misunderstood your code lol

Comment: @megawac yes, that is better.